# Why are parenscript functions changed to all lowercase?

Tags: lisp, case

When using parenscript if I execute

```
(parenscript:ps 
 (slot-value ($ "#mytextarea") 'selectionStart))
```

It produces the javascript

```
$('#mytextarea').selectionstart;
```

Note that `selectionStart` is now `selectionstart`. It lost the uppercase S on the `Start`!
How do I keep that uppercase S around?

Comment: By default, Common Lisp forms (which Parenscript takes as input) are case-folded (to uppercase) by the reader. `selectionStart` will become `SELECTIONSTART`, which Parenscript presumably then downcases when it generates JavaScript output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parenscript will automatically convert from the lisp naming convention (dashes separating words) to CamelCase, so:

```
(parenscript:ps 
 (slot-value ($ "#mytextarea") 'selection-start))
```

results in

```
"$('#mytextarea').selectionStart;"
```

Comment: If you need an initial capital letter in your symbol, you'll need to prefix the name with an asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

As Pillsy remarked, all symbols are upper-cased by default when they are read by the Lisp compiler. There is a way of turning that off, though. See the [CLHS, 23.1.2 (Effect of Readtable Case on the Lisp Reader),](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm) and the description of the accessor [`readtable-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm) for details. As an example, you can enable the “invert” mode (which is arguably the only practical setting that is also case-sensitive) by putting the following into your Lisp source file:

```
#.(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
```

Unfortunately, ParenScript does not seem to make much use of a custom readtable-case setting, even though it could (and, in my opinion, should) do so.

Comment: How would you say Parenscript can make the best use of readtable-case? The Parenscript compiler gets code as s-expressions with symbols, so it doesn't know how the symbol names were read in. There's now a compile-file function where you can customize the reader, but that won't work for all PS code.

Comment: @vsedach That's true. Still, in my opinion it's pretty clear what to do with mixed-case symbols (just leave them as they are), so the only issue left is what to do about all-uppercase and all-lowercase symbols.  Personally, I'd suggest either assuming :INVERT by default or simply down-casing all such symbols (for backwards-compatibility) and making it a setting just as READTABLE-CASE is.